# How to store a value in memory in GetxController?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

In getx Controller, I've got a value.

```
final _selectedKey = "".obs;
String get selectedKey => _selectedKey.value;
```

After I change the route to another screen, this value will change ( the controller closes when I change the screen) I need to keep the same value.

How can I store this value in my memory for however long I need it to last? Making Getx Controller Permanent is something I've seen. Is it possible to  only use this value permanent ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_storage`](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage) and get the data when you need package name.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below package to save and reflect/use your data anywhere in the application

https://pub.dev/packages/get_it

GetIt is a **service locator that allows you to create interfaces and their implementations, and access those implementations globally, anywhere in your app**.

For more information please refer to the link below
https://medium.flutterdevs.com/explore-getit-in-flutter-8db723e9d7cf

Answer (score 1):

You can use local memory by using Shared Preference or any other local storage package. But as you are using GetX for state management I would prefer to use [Get Storage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage).

- First, you must initialise Get Storage before using it somewhere. So best practice is to initialise it in the main function.

`main() async { await GetStorage.init(); runApp(App()); }`

- Now, use GetStorage through an instance.

`final box = GetStorage();`

- To write the information you must use `write` :

`box.write('key', 'value');`

- To read values you use `read`:

`box.read('key');`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a global variable and use, or you can make it a `static` variable so it never re-initialize and always still valid for use:

```
static final _selectedKey = "".obs;
static String get selectedKey => _selectedKey.value;
```

but when you need to call it, you should call it on the controller type:

```
print(MyController.selectedKey);
```